# Converter o formato de data de um array com Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Como converter o indice [date_start] para o formato 2018-08-23 12:19 com php ou laravel ?

```
Array
    (
        [id_restaurant] => 303
        [date_start] => 23/08/2018 12:19
        [date_end] => 27/08/2018 12:19
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, se você estiver trazendo esses dados por uma model (o que é recomendado), você pode transformar o seu campo do banco de dados em um objeto carbon, adicionado o nome da coluna dentro do array `$dates` da sua model.

Exemplo: `$dates = ['date_start','date_end']`

Dessa forma quando você trouxer esses dados (`$model->find($id)->date_start`) ele vai ser uma instância da classe [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), e com isso você usar o método `format()` pra jogar no modelo de data/hora que você quiser.

Exemplo: `$model->find($id)->date_start->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')`

[Referência](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Comment: Estou trazendo esses dados via request de um formulário.

Comment: Neste caso, no controller, dê um `$date_start = new Carbon($request->all()['date_start'])`, e a variável `date_start` será um objeto Carbon com os mesmos métodos.

Comment: Fiz isso que você me falou e dei um print_r para ver o retorno, deu esse erro, lembrar que importei a classe Carbon no Controller.

**Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (23/08/2018 12:19) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character in file /var/www/html/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php on line 547**

Comment: Realmente, parece que por conta dele estar no formato pt-br não consegue converter, manipula a string pra obter o dia, mês, ano, horas, minutos e segundos.
À partir disso você monta uma string com a data no formato `Y/m/d H:i:s` que ai o Carbon consegue criar.

Comment: Você também pode usar o método `createFromDate()` aonde os parâmetros dele são: 

`ano (2012), mês (08), dia (24)`. Exemplo: `$data = Carbon::createFromDate(2012,08,24)->format('d-m-Y');`

Answer (score 1):

No laravel sugiro que dê uma olhada no [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), tem bastante material lá, faz parte dos mutators que já acompanham o laravel.

ou você pode definir um mutator também (desde que esteja usando os tipos Date ou DateTime):

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d h:i:s',
];
```